# Bourbon - Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon/bourbon

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

I recently installed Bourbon Neat but when I compile my Scss in Sublime Text 2 using Sass Build I get the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon/bourbon.
```

This is my scss file:

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "neat/neat";
$desktop: new-breakpoint(min-width 768px 12);
$tablet: new-breakpoint(max-width 768px 1);

.container {
 @include outer-container;
}
.content-pri {
 @include span-columns(9);
}
.content-sec {
 @include span-columns(3);
}
```

Have I installed Bourbon and Neat incorrectly? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've never built Sass through Sublime but generally okay practice is to install Bourbon and Neat in stylesheet directory, which your `@import` path is suggesting, so check that out.

Check which libraries does ST use for that build, e.g. Compass 0.12.5 isn't compatible with Sass 3.3 and newer.

Also check this [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat#requirements) out for install instructions and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Bourbon must be on the same directory level with files which you compile with SASS. For example `scss/index.scss`.

Then, Bourbon must be installed in the `scss` directory which can be compiled with:

```
$> sass ---watch scss:css
```